# Why is virtualenv creating multiple executables in bin folder?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I’ve tried creating a virtualenv with (`virtualenv env`) and with a specific python version (`virtualenv -p —python=/usr/bin/python3.5`). It creates an environment and bin with multiple python versions. I think that is why it gives me the error “No file or directory” whenever I do `source env/bin/activate`. I’ve tried removing the extra pythons but it stills gives "no file/directory found". How can I activate an environment in python 3.5?

**Output of 
`$ virtualenv env`
or
`$ virtualenv -p —python=/usr/bin/python3.5`**

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /home/ari/differenv/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/ari/differenv/bin/python
```

So in bin there are 3 pythons which is why I think I get an error when activating the envr.

Comment: is the env/bin/activate executable?

Comment: There is an em dash in `—python`. Is that in the original command?

Comment: Please [edit] and add the full error message

Comment: Please provide full error message. There are only 2, the first one (line 1) which will be use to execute virtualenv (global one, default one), the second one (line 2 and 3) is the one that you assign for virtualenv(if you not assign any, virtualenv will use the same python which you installed virtualenv into) to copy into your virtual environment, and also create an executable alias for that with shorter name is `python` (line 3).